# Need to do Bridged Adapter only in Vagrant, no NAT

Tags: vagrant

So I'm having an issues with a Vagrant setup of 'hashicorp/precise64' on my MAC book.

First, my config:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "public_network", type: "dhcp", :bridge => 'en4: Thunderbolt Ethernet'
  config.vm.hostname = "mddirector"
end
```

This is the oupput of the 'vagrant up'

```
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions 4.3.10 running --- OK.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/garthm/Projects/vagrant
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

'ifconfig' shows the following:

```
vagrant@mddirector:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:88:0c:a6
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe88:ca6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:725 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:544 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:90824 (90.8 KB)  TX bytes:63375 (63.3 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:2f:bb:6a
          inet addr:10.0.24.118  Bcast:10.0.31.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3490 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:345981 (345.9 KB)  TX bytes:1102 (1.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

My problem is that, that I can ping the VM from my host machine (`IP: 10.0.24.112`), other people can ping my my VM too (`10.0.24.XXX`), my VM can ping my devbox (`IP: 10.10.116.254`), I can ping other developers virtual machine setups from my devbox (not Vagrant, `IP: 10.10.116.254`), but I can't ping my VM from my devbox and other developer's can't ping my VM from their devbox.

The Virtual machine setups they have is with a Bridged NIC only, but the vagrant for some reason has both a NAT and Bridged, even though, I've specified bridged in the config. As you can see, there are two IP addresses for the Vagrant VM, which doesn't seem right. You can also, when it boots up, it does a port forward on Adaptor 1, which is the NAT adaptor, which means it sounds like it's using the NAT adaptor by default for everything.

How do I get rid of the NAT adaptor and use bridged only?

If I edit the VirtualBox settings and disable the NAT adaptor, so there is only the bridged Adaptor and boot up the box via VirtualBox (ie: not using vagrant up), then it only has eth0 with a IP address that is pingable from my devbox, which is what I'm looking for. If I try and vagrant up the box after editing the VirtualBox settings and disabling the NAT adaptor, I get the following error:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["modifyvm", "7f1c12f7-74cd-4c6b-aa5a-16d6209cf2b3", "--natpf1", "ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,2222,,22"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: A NAT rule of this name already exists
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057), component NATEngine, interface INATEngine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "AddRedirect(Bstr(strName).raw(), proto, Bstr(strHostIp).raw(), RTStrToUInt16(strHostPort), Bstr(strGuestIp).raw(), RTStrToUInt16(strGuestPort))" at line 1655 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

If I immediately do a vagrant up again, it has re-enabled the NAT adaptor again, and we're back to having the same problem again.

Answer (score 28):

`eth0` as NAT is a [fundamental requirement of Vagrant in its current state](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2093). But you can override the default router configuration for `eth1`.

From the [Vagrant docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html):

> ## Default Router
>
> Depending on your setup, you may wish to manually override the default router configuration. This is required if you **need access the Vagrant box from other networks over the public network**. To do so, you can use a shell provisioner script:
>
> ```
> config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.17"
>
> # default router
> config.vm.provision "shell",
>   run: "always",
>   inline: "route add default gw 192.168.0.1"
>
> # default router ipv6
> config.vm.provision "shell",
>   run: "always",
>   inline: "route -A inet6 add default gw fc00::1 eth1"
>
> # delete default gw on eth0
> config.vm.provision "shell",
>   run: "always",
>   inline: "eval `route -n | awk '{ if ($8 ==\"eth0\" && $2 != \"0.0.0.0\") print \"route del default gw \" $2; }'`"
> ```
>
> Note the above is fairly complex and may be guest OS specific, but we document the rough idea of how to do it because it is a common question.

Answer (score 12):

(Sorry, quite naive about vagrant/virtualbox so forgive the lack of proper networking terminology)

Your choice of **bridge:  en4) Thunderbolt** is most likely the issue.

**Here's what I assume you want/need, rather than what you asked for:**

- SSH login capability for vagrant to control your vm, from your dev box (the host).  That's what the NAT with port forwarding does.  It doesn't mess anything else up, so asking for it to be gone isn't all that useful.  And that shows up on Adapter 1 in VirtualBox.
- Connectivity from your LAN, rather than just your host.  Let's say something in the 192.168.1.xxx range.  That's what's important, on Adapter 2.
- You just care about your normal network card/NIC and have no particular reason to run Ethernet over your Thunderbolt port.

i.e. pretty much what you would get from a VirtualBox vm with Bridged and no Vagrant to be seen.

Here's an SSH ifconfig from one of those VirtualBox only machines I have on my LAN.  It runs a web server I can connect to and my Mac can SSH into it and connect to a database on it.  I'll call it the *reference*.

```
[root@fdm ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:9A:85:1A
          inet addr:192.168.1.143  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

In VirtualBox, the Network panel, for that reference vm, shows Adapter1 as Bridged.  All other adapters are disabled.

OK, so I am now going to try for that same LAN connectivity result from Vagrant, but I accept that I will have a NAT at adapter 1, that's the vagrant-VB ssh communication mechanism.

## Try #1 - which fails.

Starting point is a **vagrant init**.

Then in Vagrantfile, I changed only 2 things:

```
config.vm.box = "opscode-ubuntu-14.04"
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

if I **vagrant up** this, I get a dialog asking which interface to use:

```
==> default: Available bridged network interfaces:
1) en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)
2) en0: Ethernet
3) en3: Thunderbolt 1
4) p2p0
5) bbptp0
6) bridge0
```

Now, looking at it, I first chose **2)** because I thought I wanted Ethernet and well, **1)** seemed 'too Apple'.

This works, but with an unsuitable IP 10.0.xx.xx entry, which my ISP blocks pings on, see below.  I guess they really mean public when it says public network.

**vagrant ssh**

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:0c:41:3e
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe0c:413e/64 Scope:Link

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:ca:f4:64
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feca:f464/64 Scope:Link
```

## Try #2 - correct version

**vagrant halt**, then delete the directory, create it again and **vagrant init**.  (I found that messing too much with the network could confuse the vagrant and/or virtualbox which a full removal and restart would fix)

```
config.vm.box = "opscode-ubuntu-14.04"
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

But, this time, pick 1) en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort).

**vagrant ssh**

That eth1 with 192.168.1.123 looks much nicer, doesn't it?

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:0c:41:3e
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:53:6e:1d
          inet addr:192.168.1.123  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

And, indeed, I can ping 192.168.1.123 from my reference vm, or from another physical machine on my LAN.

```
[root@fdm ~]# ping 192.168.1.123
PING 192.168.1.123 (192.168.1.123) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.123: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1039 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.123: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=40.4 ms
```

FWIW, VirtualBox shows a NAT on Adapter 1 and a Bridged on Adapter 2.

## Final setup -

Added automatic selection of the interface as well as a static IP (which you don't need).  Problem solved, for me at least.

```
  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: 'en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)', ip: "192.168.1.201"
```

### EDIT 201902:  on my latest build, vagrant/virtualbox were complaining about *Wifi (Airport)* not being found:

```
==> default: Specific bridge 'en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)' not found. You may be asked to specify
==> default: which network to bridge to.
==> default: Available bridged network interfaces:
1) en0: Ethernet
2) en2: Thunderbolt 1
3) bridge0
```

changed it to

`config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "bridge0"`

Will update later if something comes up, but thought I'd update the bit about the adapter name.

Comment: his answer deserves more credit, so simple to add an extra adapter, I didn't even get the menu (only have 1 active card).

Comment: "delete the directory" delete which directory ? you mean `.vagrant` ?

Comment: I had both "en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)" and "bridge0" and only the "bridge0" worked. I did also have to manually set the IP (DHCP didn't want to work)

Answer (score 5):

The short answer seems to be don't.

You can override adapter 1 but expect problems at least with `vagrant ssh`

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "public_network", :adapter=>1 , type: "dhcp", :bridge => 'en4: Thunderbolt Ethernet'
  config.vm.hostname = "mddirector"

  # In case you get the host wrong...
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 30
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb, override|
       vb.gui = true
  end

  config.ssh.host = '192.168.148.24'

end
```

Produces:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
    default: VirtualBox adapter #1 not configured as "NAT". Skipping port
    default: forwards on this adapter.
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
```

Unfortunately it seems to then lock up configuring the network adapter but maybe you will have more luck than me.

If you do you can always force halt and reload with a corrected `ssh.host`. Alternatively I have heard of `vagrant dns` but never tried it.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816444/vagrant-how-to-set-network-type-so-that-its-attached-to-bridge-adapter-on-virtua) on StackOverflow.

For me, it was enough to open the related `Vagrantfile` and uncomment the following line:

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

and then run `vagrant reload`

Comment: If you look at my Vagrantfile config, you'll see that the config setting is there already.

Comment: Oh sorry! I missed that.

Comment: I believe it's always going to have a NAT connection because when you do vagrant ssh or any provisioning, it's always going to access it through 127.0.0.1:2222 or whatever port it forwards to 22 on the guest box.

Comment: This is spot on answer for me.  it just adds a nic

Answer (score 0):

1 - you can not just replace `eth0` with the briged interfase or delete it, because it is needed for Vagrant itself to be able configure machine and ssh here.

2 - so, you have add the `eth1` and configure it as you need, then make default route use this interface only. (delete default gw on `eth0` and leave on `eth1` only)

> `en0: Wi-Fi` it is the name of the Wi-Fi adapter on my Mac, make sure you use correct name of your network interface here.

> `:adapter=>2` makes this adapter `eth1` inside VM

```
config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: 'en0: Wi-Fi', :adapter=>2 , type: "dhcp"
...
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  ip route del default dev eth0
SHELL
```

now the VM should have 2 network interfaces: `eth0` - NAT for vagrant access, `eth1` - bridge on the Wi-Fi adapter.

I've deleted default route in shell command from the `eth0` (NAT interface for Vagrant). Now the VM should use default route from `eth1` (breage on Wi-Fi interface) only. Done

Let's check. Routs on VM should looks like this:

```
$ ip r
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.119 metric 1024
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 1024
10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 1024
10.0.2.3 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 1024
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.119 metric 1024
192.168.0.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.119 metric 1024
```